# classlist.toggle not working for fa-check

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written the following code for toggling a dash with a check, the desired toggling is not happening:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-check");
}
```

```css
.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-minus"></i>
```

Also surprisingly, if I replace `fa-minus` with `fa-check` and vice-versa, the code seems to work!

Could anybody suggest a solution to this? As I need the first method to be working.

Comment: When only one argument is present: Toggle class value; i.e., if class exists then remove it and return false, if not, then add it and return true.
When a second argument is present: If the second argument evaluates to true, add specified class value, and if it evaluates to false, remove it.

So when your class will be `fa fa-minus fa-check` or just `fa fa-minus`
can you inspect the element and see if this how it is?

Comment: You need to toggle both classes. The **Reason** this happens is because as-written, it's adding and removing `fa-check`, but not toggling off `fa-minus`. It stays minus because `fa-minus` comes later in the FontAwesome CSS, so it has a higher priority.

Comment: **Do not use `onclick` handler, it's really bad practice.** Instead use `document.querySelector('your-selector').addEventListener('click', function() { /* click handler code here* / })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is working but `fa-check` is append to the already exist classList so when you add `fa-check` classList become `fa fa-minus fa-check` and `fa-minus` take the priority show you can not able see effect of `fa-check`. Just toggle `fa-minus` as well and you will see output. Try below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style>
.fa {
font-size: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
user-select: none;
}

.fa:hover {
color: darkblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-minus"></i>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("fa-check");
    x.classList.toggle("fa-minus");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to toggle the `fa-minus` at the same time also. As actually you are having both of them when you add the `fa-check` so one is overidding the other.

You can also rely on Font Awesome classes to increase size:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-check");
  x.classList.toggle("fa-minus");
}
```

```css
.fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-5x fa-minus"></i>
```

Comment: You ran into the same issue as me. The SO styles come before what's included in the HTML via `link`, so your `50px` don't apply.

Comment: @connexo yes i was focusing on the JS, by the way this CSS is useless as FA already provide classes to make font bigger

Answer (score 0):

Do not use inline event handlers like `onclick`, instead attach an event listener programmatically. Also you need to toggle `.fa-minus` as well, otherwise you get an element that looks like

```
<i class="fa fa-minus fa-check"></i>
```

in which case whatever class is defined later in FA's css wins.

```js
document.querySelector('.fa.fa-minus').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle("fa-check");
  e.target.classList.toggle("fa-minus");
})
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";

.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
```